# jQuery Datatable add CSS to cell after update

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am trying to add CSS to a cell after a record in my jQuery Datatable is updated. Basically to show the user that the update was successful.

I'm using a BLUR event to send the parameters over to the processing script:

```
$('#example1').on('blur', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var forecastnewval = $(this).val();

  $.post('api/inlineEditProcess.php', {forecastnewval:forecastnewval}, function(data)
  {
    changeColor(); // calling this function
    //$(this).css('background-color', 'green'); // I tried this but unsuccessful
  });
});
```

I'm calling this function:

```
function changeColor()
{
  $('#example1 tr > td > .editForecast').on('blur', function()
  {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  });
}
```

At this point, the user can make the update. But they tab/click off the cell nothing happens. The function only works when they click back into the cell and then tab/click off of it.

I know it has something to do with the fact that I already have a BLUR event going when they initially click into the cell. The function then uses another BLUR event, which explains why they have to click into the cell twice for it work.

I need it to work on the first BLUR event.

As you will see in the initial BLUR event, I did add the code to change the CSS within the $.POST, but that was unsuccessful.

I know I cannot use 2 BLUR events, but I'm not sure what else I can use to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It thinks its better to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for listening events of dynamic elements instead of binding event handler each time.

Where you can check value is changed or not by comparing current value with the `value` attribute.

```
$('#example1').on('blur', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(){
  // check value is changed or not
  if(this.value !== $(this).attr('value')){
     $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  }
});
```

---

Or better way would be tracking the current value while focusing the element(using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)) and later compare with the tracked value.

```
// list focus event to track the current value of element
$('#example1').on('focus', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(){
   $(this).data('value', this.value);
})


$('#example1').on('blur', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(){
  // compare value with the tracked value
  if(this.value !== $(this).data('value')){
     $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  }
});
```

Comment: For the most part, your code does answer my question. However, when the parameters get sent over to my processing script, there's a chance the UPDATE might fail. With that said, I only want the cell to turn green IF the update is successful. Therefore, an IF/ELSE within the Post would be necessary. This is where I think your code would not work if placed within the Post. However, your code does indeed answer my question.

Answer (score -2):

For the first event, why not use onFocus(), then use onBlur() for the second event.

Comment: Well, the UPDATE process shouldn't run until they are finished making their updates and then tab/click off the cell.  If I use onFocus, wouldn't the process attempt to run even though the user hasn't made any updates yet?