# jQuery Datatable add CSS to cell after update Part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

This is a follow-up to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383712/jquery-datatable-add-css-to-cell-after-update#48383785).

What I need to do is color the cell only after the process successfully updates the record.

```
$('#example1').on('blur', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var forecastnewval = $(this).val();
  var processData = '';

  if(this.value !== $(this).attr('value'))
  {
    $.post('api/inlineEditProcess.php', {forecastnewval:forecastnewval}, function(data)
    {
     processData = data; // this is what I'm trying to get now
     console.log('this is inside ' + processData); // this prints processData
    }

    console.log('this is outside ' + processData); // this does not print processData

    $(this).css('background-color', '#99FF66'); // this changes the background color of the cell
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('nothing changed');
  }
});
```

If you'll notice in the code above, I'm trying to retrieve the variable processData from inside the $.POST and use it in another IF/ELSE statement.

The variable processData will be a string that either reads 'success' or 'fail'. This obviously comes from a PHP process script that runs an UPDATE query, which then returns the words specified.

I want to utilize processData in an IF/ELSE that will change the background color of the cell either to green (for success) or red (for fail).

I simply want to retrieve the variable that was created from within the $.POST.

Can I do this, and if so, how?

Comment: if you declare the variable `processData` outside the post function, it should work. You are probably going to print undefined right now because you declared the variable inside the function's scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `processData` is enclosed within a function so will return `null` when evaluated outside of it.

```js
$('#example1').on('blur', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var forecastnewval = $(this).val();
  var processData = "";

  if (this.value !== $(this).attr('value')) {
    $.post('api/inlineEditProcess.php', {
      forecastnewval: forecastnewval
    }, function(data) {
      processData = data; // this is what I'm trying to get now
    });

    console.log(processData); // this does not print processData

    $(this).css('background-color', '#99FF66'); // this changes the background color of the cell
  } else {
    console.log('nothing changed');
  }
});
```

Comment: I updated my code. Please see the console.logs - I am only able to print processData from inside the Post.  I cannot access it outside of the post. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the `post` function was not closed correctly. Ammended in my answer.